# How to retrive sharepoint list data using Search query in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: splist, search-query

Currently i receiving data from sharepoint list using CAML and Linq.
but now requirement is to retrive data from sharepoint list using search query.

can anyone give examples or good articles to retrive data through sharepoint search query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FullTextSqlQuery like it's described in [this post](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/03/06/how-to-use-the-moss-enterprise-search-fulltextsqlquery-class.aspx) or KeywordQuery like it's described in [this post](http://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/mark-jones/2012/12/12/how-to-use-search-%28keywordquery%29-to-query-user-profiles-in-sharepoint#.US8LWmda-Hs). How to choose between these two approaches you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms544561%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks alexandar your answer help me a lot...
can we query against sharepoint list? if yes then how?
And how many types of scope avaiable?

Comment: See [this video](http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-search-scope-for-a-sharepoint-2010-list-or-library/) to understand how to create scope for list. Also you can find a list of available scopes in your search settings (Site Actions > Site Settings > Search scopes).