# Limit search result to documents only but also exclude folders

Tags: 2010, search, keywordquery

I'm using a KeywordQuery within a **custom Webpart** on a SP2010 farm to aggregate the latest "documents" from the site collection the webpart is running at ("document" = every item stored in a document library **except the folders**).

Within the QueryString I limit the results to `contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary`, but folders are still present in the search results.

I’ve tried using `IsDocument:1` but then the results are too limited, because there are some file types not registered in the Search Service Application file type pool, e.g. "RTF", "RAR", "PNG", ...

Do I really have to register every file type within the SSA to expand `IsDocument` or are there other ways to exclude the folders from the results?

Comment: have you provide RowLimit of your keyword query to extend search result ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly: I've set RowLimit to 10 as I only want to receive a fixed number of results, e.g. "the ten latest (last modified) items from all document libraries". So it's more of a **filter** as an expand of the result.

Comment: plz visit answer section of this post
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60676/how-to-retrive-sharepoint-list-data-using-search-query-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get you. Maybe I should have been more precisely: I know how to use KeywordQuery and KQL in C# code and I want to reuse the webpart on multiple sites. So a search scope as described in that other post won't fit my needs to exclude folders from the search result, would it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To exclude the Folders try adding "Size>0" to your query and see if that helps.