# Search Result source Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

How can modify below search result sources so it only take documents and not folders and also not any other pages from document libraries

```
{searchTerms} path: https://sharepoint.com/Test/Test/sites/DocumentLibrary* IsDocument=True
```

Comment: Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85524/limit-search-result-to-documents-only-but-also-exclude-folders), let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use:

```
{searchTerms} path: https://sharepoint.com/Test/Test/sites/DocumentLibrary IsDocument=1
```